# Simple way to get OAuth for facebook

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, oauth

I'm building an app that requires login for Facebook to send the OAuth token to the server.

The Facebook API is a bit bulky and adds a lot that I do not need. I was using share kit, but then realized that it doesn't use OAuth but rather the deprecated session key method.

I poked around github and done some searching but haven't found something the seems to be what I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: How do I get Facebook Oauth token in an iPhone app without using the Facebook iOS API. The Facebook API does not seem to work on Xcode 4.2

Comment: I found a great solution that was incredibly simple using UIWebview:http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 2):

You could probably implement your own stripped-down 'SDK' with just the authentication code, but i think it'd be a lot of hassle for not much benefit - the authentication docs are at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and should give enough info to implement login from scratch - not sure it'd be easy to implement the IOS SSO functionality though - this may be tied closely with the Facebook IOS SDK